# How to set buttons in popup to appear vertically

Tags: objective-c, macos

[image]

For this to appear like this my code is

```
- (int)ldapAlertMessage:(NSString *)alertMessage
{
    int x=0;
    if (nil != alertMessage) {
        NSImage *alertIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"security_alert_icon"];
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc]init];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
         [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [alert setMessageText:alertMessage];
        [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
        [alert setIcon:alertIcon];
        [[alert window] setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
        int result= [alert runModal];
        switch(result)
        {
    case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
            {
                x=1;
                return x;
                break;
            }
    case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
            {
                x=2;
                return x;
                break;
            }

            case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn:
            {
                x=3;
                return x;
                break;
            }

        }
           }

    return x;

}
```

Called by using

```
   user_response = [self ldapAlertMessage: @"You will no longer be able to access your ldap login on this device if you select this."];
```

according to user response action defined under buttons execute.

I want a method to know how can i make my buttons to appear vertically as i will change text yes, no to something bigger.

Comment: You can use `UIActionSheet` instead of `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Even i am having same question. Is there any way to get checkboxes and radio buttons in a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could use a custom Window that you load on alert as YourAlertView or use `accessoryView` with your custom view placed inside the `NSAlertView`.